# How can I download SSRS 2016 Installation File Only?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, installation, sql-server-2016

I need a file from SSRS 2016 installation without SQL server Installation setup. A separated file. where can I download That?

[here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4852/sql-server-reporting-services-standalone-installation/) I found a clue. but link not work.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% but I believe you can no longer get 2016 from the Microsoft website however, you could use 2017, this is found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252).

This is compatible with SQl Server 2008 SP4 and above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Tom. if noOne answer best , I will mark this post as Answer

Comment: @mahdimoghimi, Thank you :)